# Multipath routing to the local LAN. Why can't I add default route? Why can I remove static route afterwards?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, gateway

I have a host with two NICs, each connected to separate switches on the same LAN (`10.0.0.0/16`). The switches are each connected to the local gateway. All the hosts on one switch are in the subnet `10.0.0.8/29` and all the hosts on the other switch are in the subnet `10.0.0.16/29`.

My goal is that traffic leaving this host should use the switch most appropriate for the destination, if it's in one of the two `/29` subnets. If it's anywhere else on the LAN it can take either path. I'd also like it to be the case that if either switch dies, traffic will continue to flow to both addresses on the host uninterrupted.

```
$ ip -4 addr show enp5s0
16: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.9/29 scope global enp5s0
$ ip -4 addr show enp6s0
17: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.17/29 scope global enp6s0
```

```
$ ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 \
    nexthop dev enp5s0 \
    nexthop dev enp6s0

$ ip route
10.0.0.0/16 
    nexthop dev enp5s0 weight 1 linkdown 
    nexthop dev enp6s0 weight 1 
10.0.0.8/29 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.9 linkdown 
10.0.0.16/29 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.17
```

I have setup the host with the above routes and address and communication to the gateway 10.0.0.1 works fine. However, I'm running into an issue when trying to add the default route.

```
$ sudo ip route add default nexthop via 10.0.0.1  
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

I thought that, by leaving off gateway addresses on the multipath route to `10.0.0.0/16`, that linux would realize that it is a directly connected LAN. I can add an explicit route to the gateway via one of the interfaces, but not both. After adding an explicit route then I can add the default because linux knows it's a directly connected subnet.

```
$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.1/32 dev enp6s0
$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.1/32 dev enp5s0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
$ sudo ip route add default via 10.0.0.1
$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp6s0 
10.0.0.0/16 
    nexthop dev enp5s0 weight 1 linkdown 
    nexthop dev enp6s0 weight 1 
10.0.0.1 dev enp6s0 scope link 
10.0.0.8/29 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.9 linkdown 
10.0.0.16/29 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.17
```

Annoyingly, I can *delete* the explicit route at this point and everything continues to work -- even if I flush the gateway from the ARP cache!

```
$ sudo ip route del 10.0.0.1
$ sudo ip neigh flush 10.0.0.1
$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp6s0 
10.0.0.0/16 
    nexthop dev enp5s0 weight 1 linkdown 
    nexthop dev enp6s0 weight 1 
10.0.0.8/29 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.9 linkdown 
10.0.0.16/29 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.17 
$ ping -n -c 1 10.0.0.1 | grep icmp_seq
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.492 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you must tell linux that the multipath route is part of the local network by adding `scope link` and you must also use a multipath route for the `default` route.

```
$ ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 scope link \
    nexthop dev enp5s0 \
    nexthop dev enp6s0

$ ip route add default \
    nexthop via 10.0.0.1 dev enp5s0 \
    nexthop via 10.0.0.1 dev enp6s0

$ ip route
default
    nexthop via 10.0.0.1 dev enp5s0 weight 1 linkdown
    nexthop via 10.0.0.1 dev enp6s0 weight 1
10.0.0.0/16 scope link 
    nexthop dev enp5s0 weight 1 linkdown
    nexthop dev enp6s0 weight 1 
10.0.0.8/29 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.9 linkdown
10.0.0.16/29 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.17
```